# using two references of j queries of different versions

Tags: jquery

I want to refer two different references of the jquery of different version. I am having 1.11.2 and 1.8.3 versions. I want to use only one at a time. I am referencing higher version which is 1.11.2 on master page but my one page needs 1.8.3 version. I want to refer only one at a time when i am on that page where it requires 1.8.3 I don't want to refer 1.11.2 versions jquery. How I can control the referencing only one at a time. 
Can anyone help me for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery.noConflict, you can make multiple versions of jQuery coexist on the same page.  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/